# I need help setting up foreign key constraints in my MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I'm sorry I can't create a more specific question in the title; it's likely due to my unfamiliarity with the terminology.

Here's a simplified diagram of the portion of the MySQL database I'm working with:

[image]

Example data might be:

- **recipe**: "Apple pie"
- **recipeIngredientItem**: "3 cups + 2 tbsp all-purpose flour"
- **recipeStep**: "Preheat oven to 400°F"
- **ingredient**: "all-purpose flour"
- **compoundMeasurement**: "3 cups + 2 tbsp"
- **simpleMeasurement**: "3 cups"
- **measurementUnit**: "cup"

If I delete a recipe, I wasn't it to cascade and delete all associated *recipeIngredientItems* and *recipeSteps*. However, there are a few complications:

- If a *recipeIngredientItem* is deleted, I want the associated *compoundMeasurement* deleted, and in turn any *simpleMeasurement*s that are associated with that *compoundMeasurement*. But I do NOT want associated *ingredient*s and *measurementUnit*s deleted.
- I'm not sure what I want to do when an *ingredient* or *measurementUnit* is deleted, but I am figuring my UI will warn the user and handle appropriately ("Warning! If you delete the ingredient "all-purpose flour," it will be removed from all recipes where it is used.").
- Also, my intention was to use *compoundMeasurement* in other ways, for example in association with a *pantryItem* table to manage inventory. So having a "recipeIngredientItem" key column in *compoundMeasurement* wouldn't make sense. However, if this is bad design, I could have separate *recipeCompoundMeasurement* and *pantryItemCompoundMeasurement* tables. It just seemed like an unnecessary complication, but that may well reflect my amateurish self-taught database knowledge. :)

How should I set up foreign key constraints for these tables? Or would it be better to redesign the database somehow?

EDIT:

For what it's worth, here's what I have working so far (as far as constraints), though I'm not sure if it's the most elegant solution. All constraints are set to cascade on delete or change:

```
recipeIngredientItem.amount: links to compoundMeasurement.idNumber
recipeIngredientItem.ingredient: links to ingredient.idNumber
recipeIngredientItem.recipe: links to recipe.idNumber

recipeStep.recipe: links to recipe.idNumber

simpleMeasurement.measurementUnit: links to measurementUnit.idNumber
simpleMeasurement.compoundMeasurement: links to compoundMeasurement.idNumber
```

With these in place, when I delete a *recipe*, the associated *recipeIngredientItem*s and *recipeStep*s are deleted, but I need to go through and explicitly delete the *compoundMeasurement*s associated with the deleted *recipeIngredientItem*s (which in turn delete the associated *measurement*s). It's easy enough to do, of course, just slightly inelegant. But maybe that's the cost of using *compoundMeasurement* in multiple ways...

Answer (score 0):

Sigh.

The obvious solution was to redesign my database to reduce abject ludicrosity, but you all knew that already.